# require once out of scope inside function

Tags: php

I have classes included on my bootstrap.php and variables instantiated on the classes included, When I included bootstrap.php it gives me a Call to a member function on a non object

bootstrap.php

```
require_once "config/constants.php";
require_once "libraries/Dropbox/DropboxClient.php";

$dropbox = new DropboxClient(array(
'app_key' => DROPBOX_CONSUMER_KEY, 
'app_secret' => DROPBOX_CONSUMER_SECRET,
'app_full_access' => true,
),'en');
```

index.php

```
require_once "bootstrap.php";

dropbox_file_tree();

function dropbox_file_tree()
{
     if(!empty($access_token)) {

     $dropbox->SetAccessToken($access_token);

     }

    $files = $dropbox->GetFiles("",true); 

    print_r($files);
}
```

Comment: You need to pass the `$dropbox` instance to the function then. Each function does have its own local scope; being empty per default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's nothing to do with `include`, it's a [scope issue](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php), functions only see local variables.

You have to use the `global` keyword or the `$GLOBALS` superglobal or pass it as a parameter to the function.

Comment: Only use globals when absolutely necessary!  I wouldn't consider this case necessary.  Though there maybe a reason he's declaring the dropbox client in the bootstrap file, then trying to access it in index.php.  Looks like bad structure.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the dropbox object to the function

```
dropbox_file_tree($dropbox);

function dropbox_file_tree($dropbox)
{
    if(!empty($access_token)) {
        $dropbox->SetAccessToken($access_token);
    }

    $files = $dropbox->GetFiles("",true); 

    print_r($files);
}
```

Comment: Or better yet, write your own wrapper for the Client with the extra functionality you require.

Comment: True, not that its been declared anywhere in the example anyway.  I think the OP needs to rethink his solution.